# How can I dispatch an action to my store before I server side render? - Redux

Tags: redux, server-side-rendering

I have an app that I am server side rendering.  Here is the server side code:

```js
export default (req, res, next) => {
    const store = getStore();

    // HERE IS THE DISPATCH
    getStore().dispatch(updateToken("TOKEN"));

    match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {

        if (err) {
            return next(err);

        } else if (redirect) {
            res.redirect(redirect.pathname + redirect.search)

        } else if (props) {

            resolveAsyncDeps(store, props)
                .then(() => {

                    //HERE IS INITIAL STATE
                    const initialState = store.getState();

                    const content = renderToString(
                        <Provider store={store}>
                            <RouterContext {...props} />
                        </Provider>
                    );

                    res.send(
                        minify(
                            docTemplate({
                                ...(Helmet.rewind()),
                                content,
                                initialState,
                                env: { DASHBOARD_REST_API, DASHBOARD_WS_API }
                            }),
                            { collapseWhitespace: true, removeAttributeQuotes: false }
                        )
                    );
                }).catch(next);



        } else {
            res.status(404).send('Not Found')
        }
    })
}
```

My action is synchronous:

```js
export function updateToken(token) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_TOKEN,
    payload: {
      token
    }
  };
}
```

But when I `getState()` on the `store` to pass down as `initialState`, my `token` is not in the state tree.  I thought `dispatch` was synchronous, unless I was using a `thunk` or some other type of middleware?  What am I missing?  How do I add something to the `initialState` before I push to the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, I imagine `getStore` is a factory function -- a factory function that calls Redux's `createStore` but with application-specific configuration.

On the server, unless you want all users & requests to share the same store instance, a new store instance must be created on each request.

Looking at your code snippet:

```js
const store = getStore();

// HERE IS THE DISPATCH
getStore().dispatch(updateToken("TOKEN"));
```

It appears like you have created two store instances per request, and are dispatching the `updateToken("TOKEN")` action into the wrong instance of the store.

Instead, you probably want to do something like:

```js
const store = getStore();

// HERE IS THE DISPATCH
store.dispatch(updateToken("TOKEN"));
```

This will dispatch the `updateToken("TOKEN")` action into the only store instance in that request.